# M2.4.2 - Full Page Cache and Redis

Tags: magento2.4, redis

Is it normal that FPC set the whole page markup/source code into Redis?

```
1625547914.235475 [1 172.26.0.1:51586] "hmset" "zc:k:bcf_MAGE_RUN_TYPE_STORE_MAGE_RUN_CODE_EN_0BC9BA06D17818C5EB80EAB9C0B5876D3A7807D0" "d" "{\"content\":\" <!doctype html> <html class=\\\"use-header3\\\" lang=\\\"en\\\"><head ><!-- # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # Developed and Powered by Domain, Ltd - https:\\/\\/www.domain.com # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # -->  <meta charset=\\\"utf-8\\\"\\/>\\n<meta name=\\\"title\\\" content=\\\"Personal Care\\\"\\/>\\n<meta name=\\\"description\\\" content=\\\"Domain Online Store\\\"\\/>\\n<meta name=\\\"keywords\\\" content=\\\"Domain , Varien, E-commerce ,Domain Commerce|\\u0627\\u064a\\u0646\\u0645\\u0627\\\"\\/>\\n<meta name=\\\"robots\\\" content=\\\"INDEX,FOLLOW\\\"\\/>\\n<meta name=\\\"viewport\\\" content=\\\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\\\"\\/>\\n<title>Personal Care<\\/title>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/mage\\/calendar.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/css\\/local.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/Amasty_Label\\/vendor\\/tooltipster\\/css\\/tooltipster.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/Aramex_Shipping\\/css\\/aramex.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/Aramex_Shipping\\/css\\/aramexcalculator.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_Mpanel\\/css\\/owl.carousel.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_Mpanel\\/css\\/owl.theme.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_Mpanel\\/css\\/animate.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_Mpanel\\/css\\/magnific-popup.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/Magento_Swatches\\/css\\/swatches.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_Lookbook\\/css\\/styles.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_Mmegamenu\\/css\\/megamenu.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_Promobanners\\/css\\/promobanners.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/Vnecoms_Sms\\/css\\/intlTelInput.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/css\\/bootstrap.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/css\\/font-awesome.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/css\\/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/css\\/menu.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/css\\/theme_default.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/css\\/theme.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/css\\/responsive.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_Mpanel\\/css\\/color.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_Ajaxlayernavigation\\/css\\/ajaxlayernavigation.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog\\/css\\/priceslider.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_InstantSearch\\/css\\/styles.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/Amasty_Label\\/css\\/source\\/mkcss\\/amlabels.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/unpkg.com\\/swiper\\/swiper-bundle.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\"  media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/MGS_Brand\\/css\\/mgs_brand.min.css\\\" \\/>\\n\\n<link  rel=\\\"icon\\\" type=\\\"image\\/x-icon\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/media\\/favicon\\/default\\/favicon.png\\\" \\/>\\n<link  rel=\\\"shortcut icon\\\" type=\\\"image\\/x-icon\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/media\\/favicon\\/default\\/favicon.png\\\" \\/>\\n<meta property=\\\"og:title\\\" content=\\\"Domain\\\" \\/>\\r\\n<meta property=\\\"og:type\\\" content=\\\"website\\\" \\/>\\r\\n<meta property=\\\"og:url\\\" content=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/en\\/\\\" \\/>\\r\\n<meta property=\\\"og:image\\\" content=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/pub\\/media\\/catalog\\/category\\/DOMAIN1.jpg\\\" \\/>        \\n    ##ga4_snippet_scripts##    <!-- Facebook Business Extension for Magento 2 --><!-- Facebook Pixel Code --><noscript> <img height=\\\"1\\\" width=\\\"1\\\" style=\\\"display:none\\\" src=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/tr?id=501877977599420&ev=PageView&noscript=1&a=magento2-2.4.2-1.4.2\\\" \\/><\\/noscript><!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->       <link rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" type=\\\"text\\/css\\\" media=\\\"all\\\" href=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/media\\/mgs\\/css\\/1\\/custom_config.css\\\" \\/><\\/head><body data-container=\\\"body\\\" data-mage-init='{\\\"loaderAjax\\\": {}, \\\"loader\\\": { \\\"icon\\\": \\\"https:\\/\\/www.domain.com\\/static\\/version1625539783\\/frontend\\/Domain\\/domain\\/en_US\\/images\\/loader-2.gif\\\"}}' id=\\\"html-body\\\" class=\\\"page-with-filter page-products categorypath-personal-care category-personal-care catalog-category-view page-layout-2columns-left width1366 wide\\\">     <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->\\r\\n<noscript><iframe src=\\\"https:\\/\\/www.googletagmanager.com\\/ns.html?id=GTM-K6RBX8P\\\"\\r\\nheight=\\\"0\\\" width=\\\"0\\\" style=\\\"display:none;visibility:hidden\\\"><\\/iframe><\\/noscript>\\r\\n<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->           <div id=\\\"cookie-status\\\">The store will not work correctly in the case when cookies are disabled.<\\/div>        <noscript><div class=\\\"message global noscript\\\"><div class=\\\"content\\\"><p><strong>JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser.<\\/strong> <span>For the best experience on our site, be sure to turn on Javascript in your browser.<\\/span><\\/p><\\/div><\\/div><\\/noscript>      <main><div class=\\\"page-wrapper  lazy-loading-img\\\" data-ratioimage=\\\"ratio-4\\\"><div id=\\\"placeholder-header\\\"><\\/div><header class=\\\"header header3\\\">                                                     <div class=\\\"top-header-content\\\"><div class=\\\"container\\\"><div class=\\\"row\\\"><div class=\\\"col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12\\\"><!-- Static block: header_aqe
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... yes :) how else would the cache serve the page? the basic concept of caching is that you keep a fully-generated *'copy'* of the page *somewhere*  and serve it from that place without the need to load the whole application, query the database and process all the assets needed to build that page.

Reference https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/cache-full-page.html

Comment: If so, then I would rather keep it off Redis and utilise some other means to support FPC i.e Cloudflare or even varnish, as currently Redis using over 25GB of my ram and that is way too much in my opinion and against the purpose.